# How to stay in contact with multiple recruiters from same company?

Tags: communication, recruitment

I attended my school's Career Fair recently and spoke with a few companies there that I was interested in. I ended up talking to two different recruiters from the *same* company, both of which gave me their cards and told me to stay in touch.

Since they both work at the same company, how should I handle keeping in touch? Should I email them *together*, separately, or simply choose one recruiter to keep in contact with? I'm a little lost on how to handle this situation in the most mature and professional way possible, and any insight or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send an email in one of the following ways:

- TO: Both of them
- TO: One of them, CC: The other.

  - This may be more appropriate if responding more directly to one of the recruiters, i.e. asking a direct question regarding the individual conversation
- TO: A generic email address, likely shared in the team

This approach will allow the recruiters to stay in sync.  If they decide one of them should take point with you, they can work that out on their own.

Ultimately, it probably won't be a big deal either way, as long as you are not causing them to have two separate, concurrent conversations.  That would be confusing and annoying.

Answer (score 2):

Pick one and work with that person. There won't be any hurt feelings I promise you; accepting someone's business card does not mean you are required to follow up with that person and the recruiters know that very well.

There is no added benefit to you to email both of them since they work to fill the same positions and it will only waste one of the recruiters time.

Answer (score -1):

I would contact them separately but definitely keep in touch with both of them. They might be recruiting for two different hiring manager and you don't know where the first lead or better lead is going to come from. But definitely I would contact them separately. It is cheesy to write letters starting with *Dear Mark/James,* Your notes should be personal and referencing something you discussed at the career fair. Better if it is something related to the company but if you can not recall, it might be a reference to a sporting event, concert etc that you talked about. It gives the sense of taking time to remember this person individually, rather than remembering them as a talking head, at an event you once attended. If these two people happen to talk to each other and your name gets mentioned, they definitely will compare notes and more genuine you look will increase your chances of being contacted in the future. More time you put in a relationship, regardless what kind of a relationship it is, more you will get out of it. It is the gist of the story.

Comment: If they are from a recruiting company they'll match him to every job they have available that fits his profile. If they are looking to hire direct, they probably work with HR and thus will again match him to every open position they have.

Comment: I would use this if working with two recruiters from different agencies on behalf of a company. If dealing with a company's internal team, I disagree with this answer.